# How to find the type of a variable in Chapel

Tags: chapel

It seems I come across the answer, then I lose it.  I'm at the "lost" stage.  If I have an object in Chapel, what is the equivalent of Python's

```
>>> thing = 'i am a thing'
>>> type(thing)
<type 'str'>
```

I have seen that `writeln(A.type)` and `writeln(type(A))` both throw errors of the form

```
'writeln(type _array(DefaultSparseArr(real(64),2,int(64),DefaultSparseDom(2,int(64),_domain(DefaultRectangularDom(2,int(64),false))))))'
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:3992: note: candidates are: channel.writeln(out error: syserr) [233811]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:3998: note:                 channel.writeln() [233840]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:4006: note:                 channel.writeln(const args ...?k, out error: syserr) [233876]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:4012: note:                 channel.writeln(const args ...?k) [233916]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:4020: note:                 channel.writeln(const args ...?k, style: iostyle) [233954]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:4047: note:                 channel.writeln(const args ...?k, style: iostyle, out error: syserr) [233998]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:4267: note:                 writeln(const args ...?n) [235140]
$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/IO.chpl:4273: note:                 writeln() [235158]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = 1;
writeln(x.type:string);
```

Comment: `core-test.chpl:12: error: unresolved call 'type _array(DefaultSparseArr(real(64),2,int(64),DefaultSparseDom(2,int(64),_domain(DefaultRectangularDom(2,int(64),false))))).string'
core-test.chpl:12: note: unresolved call had id 194596
make: *** [core] Error 1
`  Should I file a bug?

Comment: :string not .string